# Python Regex: Ignore Brackets

Tags: python, regex

```
LIST = ['ichenbsdr1.chen.com', 'ichenbsds1(SSI15170CCD)',
        'ichenbsds1', 'ichenbsdm2.chen.com',
        'ichenbsdm2.chen.com(ABQB344DEGH)', 'ichenbsdm2']
```

Need to filter using regex on above list. whichever the index got
brackets need to be removed with the information. `LIST[1]` is
`'ichenbsds1(SSI15170CCD)'`, have to remove `"(SSI15170CCD)"` and show
`'ichenbsds1'` alone same as in LIST[4] as well.

I have this regex `r'(.*?)\(.*\)'` to remove brackets and whatever
present inside those brackets. But when i run in the below script its
not giving exact output.

```
sws=[]
for line in LIST:
    Type = re.search(r'(.*?)\(.*\)', line)
    sws.append(Type)
    print (sws)
```

Expected Output:

```
['ichenbsdr1.chen.com', 'ichenbsds1', 'ichenbsds1', 'ichenbsdm2.chen.com', 'ichenbsdm2.chen.com', 'ichenbsdm2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` to remove everything between parenthesis

```
>>> [re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', s) for s in LIST]
['ichenbsdr1.chen.com', 'ichenbsds1', 'ichenbsds1', 'ichenbsdm2.chen.com', 'ichenbsdm2.chen.com', 'ichenbsdm2']
```